# homotopy equivalence of projective resolutions

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $P_{\bullet}$ and $P'_{\bullet}$ be projective resolutions of a module $M$ over a commutative ring $R$. Then $P_{\bullet}$ and $P'_{\bullet}$ are homotopy equivalent (see e.g. Matsumura, CRT, p.278). But both complexes $P_{\bullet}$, $P'_{\bullet}$ are exact, since they are resolutions, and so their homologies at every positive dimension are zero. So my question is: does the statement "these two complexes are homotopy equivalent" contain any nontrivial information at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two complexes could be quasi-isomorphic yet not be homotopy equivalent. Homotopy equivalence is a much stronger property than quasi-isomorphism.

The fact that any two projective resolutions are homotopy equivalent implies, for instance, that their images under any additive functor are also homotopy equivalent, hence quasi-isomorphic. This would be false if we had only required the initial complexes to be quasi-isomorphic: additive functors do not necessarily preserve quasi-isomorphisms. In fact, the whole theory of derived functors can be viewed as a (very successful) attempt at capturing the extent to which an additive functor fails to preserve quasi-isomorphisms.

Have you seen the construction of derived functors? The importance of the proposition you state should be clear once you understand this construction.